# Commandline L2TP connection?

Tags: command-line, networking, server, 18.04, vpn

I'm looking to connect to a L2TP VPN server, from ubuntu commandline. Ubuntu 18.04.

I've already done it via a desktop ubuntu. By which I mean: added l2tp network manager, configured it and connected properly.

For CLI, this guide seems properly explained:

https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#configure-linux-vpn-clients-using-the-command-line

I added `ike` and `esp` to my configuration, but besides that nothing changed.

It fails at the step where it's expected that a new interface ppp0 shows up. When I try adding it, it fails.

Despite running, every command with no error codes, it fails to connect.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively you could use the NetworkManager CLI with the `nmcli` command.

- list all NM connections: `nmcli con`
- bring up VPN connection : `nmcli con up id VPN-Connection-Name`
- bring down VPN connection: `nmcli con down id VPN-Connection-Name`

Where *VPN-Connection-Name* is the actual name of the VPN connection as listed in the `nmcli con` output.

*If you're on the same computer you're already successfully connecting on via the GUI, that should be all you need. If you're on a different machine:*

You'll need to copy the corresponding NetworkManager VPN connection profile file which is stored under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` from the desktop Ubuntu to the computer you want to use the command-line.

To pickup the new VPN connection profile file (or even changes to that file if you edit it), issue the following:

- `nmcli con reload`

Be sure to to install `network-manager-l2tp`, you won't need the GNOME GUI `network-manager-l2tp-gnome` package.

```
sudo apt install network-manager-l2tp resolvconf
```

Comment: This ended up working for me. Also had trouble on windows, a regedit fix and reboot was needed: https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients.md#windows-error-809